# Virtualbox , Ubuntu 11.10 , linux-kernel 3: cannot start virtual machine

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I've got installed oracle virtualBox v.4.1.2_Ubuntu r38359.
The program VM starts with errors:

> WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
>      Please install the virtualbox-ose-dkms package and the appropriate
>      headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.
>
> You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.

```
(VirtualBox:5642): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(VirtualBox:5642): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(VirtualBox:5642): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(VirtualBox:5642): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
```

As supposed i've done:
1)

> sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose virtualbox-ose-dkms

the answer:

> virtualbox-ose is already the newest version.
>   virtualbox-ose-dkms is already the newest version.

2)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

answer:

> linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic-pae is already the newest version.

---

If i try to launch virtual machine i got 2 windows: 
1) The first:

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine winxp.
>   The virtual machine 'winxp' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1.
>
> Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) 
>   Component: Machine  
>   Interface: IMachine {5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91}

2) The second:

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>   Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and execute 'modprobe vboxdrv' as root.

Tried:

> $sudo modprobe vboxdrv
>   FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found.

;

> $ /etc/init.d/virtualbox start 
>   * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules 
>   * No suitable module for running kernel found [fail]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried to build the kernel module?. It should have been builded during the installation, but it looks like it failed. You can try:

```
sudo dkms install virtualbox/4.1.2
```

This should build the module.

Comment: Built OK but still assuming the same problem; Should i show you the output text after "sudo dkms build virtualbox/4.1.2"?

Comment: Sure, it could help. You can also remove VirtualBox and install it from the Oracle repositories as hhlp suggested.

Comment: "Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
make KERNELRELEASE=3.0.0-12-generic-pae -C /lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic-pae/build M=/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.2/build..............
cleaning build area....

DKMS: build Completed.
"
"
ted@calister:~$ virtualbox 
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
  Please install the virtualbox-ose-dkms package and the appropriate
  headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

  You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
" Still the same error

Comment: You will need to do the /etc/init.d/virtualbox start to load the modules.

Comment: I've tried to do that. Look up in my question, please.

Comment: Yes, I did read it, but did you do it after building the modules?. Sorry, but it's not clear on the question, not in the comments, at least for me. And if you did, did it give you the same error? (it shouldn't if the module has been built ok).

Comment: Sorry for late answer, yes, still the old problem

Comment: Can you post the complete building messages to pastebin or a similar site?

Comment: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ELJ98XcK) Here's pastebin.
This is the first time i've done dkms build -- [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/60ntq2W3)

Comment: That talks great about dkms, it is supposed to work by itself. Try sudo dkms install virtualbox/4.1.2

Answer (score 3):

Go to Dash and then software center and delete all virtualbox package...

**Adding VirtualBox repository:**

```
    sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian oneiric contrib"
    wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
    sudo apt-get update
```

**Installing VirtualBox 4.1:**

```
    sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.1
```

If you want USB 2.0, VirtualBox RDP and PXE boot for Intel cards support on your guest machines, you have to install extension pack that can be downloaded [here](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.1.4/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.1.4-74291.vbox-extpack).

**Installing extension pack**

Once extension pack downloaded, open VirtualBox and navigate to "File -> Preferences", at the "Extensions" section, click icon "Add package" and locate your downloaded extension pack.

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

---

Follow your petition :

```
sudo apt-get install kernel-package 
sudo apt-get install linux-source
```

Try removing the old module.

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-ose-modules*
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-ose-modules*
```

Then install the new one.

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose-modules-`uname -r`
```

and Try this

> sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup

Comment: Cannot download the virtualBox again to due lack of traffic. Need to solve it without whole reinstalling if possible (to use as less traffic as possible).

Comment: "sudo apt-get install kernel-package ", "sudo apt-get install linux-source" that's about 82Mb to download -- impossible(traffic limit).
Nothing to remove or purge. Cannot download "E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'virtualbox-ose-modules-3.0.0-12-generic-pae'
" . Last "sudo: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: command not found"

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea!, but I got the problem like you. I just tried to solve by install vbox version support on kernel version. it worked fine. I mean that if ur vbox version is 4.X.X support which is your os kernel version ( your computer). If you want check kernel version, go to terminal type: *uname -s* .

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing that strikes me, is that you seem to be mixing the open source and proprietary versions of VirtualBox. I don't know if that's significant, but it may.

Make sure you're running the open source version of VirtualBox, or install the drivers for the proprietary version with the package [virtualbox-dkms](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/virtualbox-dkms)

Comment: already installed.

Comment: virtualbox-dkms is not proprietary. They are kernel drivers, but open-source. The proprietary parts of virtual box are now in the extension pack.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did the following:

1. Go here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads and download from there the Virtualbox Package
2. Download from the site link the Extension Pack
3. Install the package (Do not worry about the PPA/Repository or anything since the package will eventually add it to your repo)
4. Install the Extension Pack using the Virtualbox Manager

NOTE - To save yourself from problems you must eliminate the virtualbox you have installed and any repositories related to it.

After this, when an update appears the System will notify you about it like all other Ubuntu programs.

The current version right now is **4.1.4**

Comment: Another problem is that i cannot re-download virtualbox because of traffic limit

Comment: OOHH!. And from a friend's home, cafe place, girlfriend's, mom's, the neighbor?

Comment: I'm not in my native town for those variants except cafe places but hopefully solution will come without it

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Ubuntu Software Center GUI, rather than having to use the apt-get command line

Search for Virtualbox

- Should get at least two hits.
- First remove x86 virtualization solution-base binaries (highlight and click remove)
- Then highlight and remove Virtualbox

Once both are removed, install Virtualbox

- This will automatically re-install the base binaries and rebuild the Virtualbox kernel

That should do it.

Comment: Already solved with **Javier Rivera** help. Thank you, nevertheless ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem:
`"WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv` does not exist. Please install the `virtualbox-ose-dkms` package and the appropriate headers, most likely `linux-headers-generic`." Even though all VirtualBox packages were installed.

1. Uninstall all virtualbox: `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox`
2. Go to the:
   https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads (Download the one for Ubuntu 12.10 my case)
3. Install the package.
4. All is working fine now and have a lot of fun with Linux!

Comment: yeah, but in my case i couldn't afford to download a new package

Answer (score -1):

What solved the problem for me is simply reinstalling - first purge the base package and any related config files:

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox
```

And then install it once again (assuming you also want the GUI):

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-qt
```

I upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04, so I'm assuming some of the drivers or configs got messed up in the transition.

Comment: Sure that would work, but in my case that was unacceptable solution

Comment: Then why not mention this requirement in the question?