# cannot run virtualbox on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization

The virtualBox used to work properly and there was no error before.Now I can't run any of the VMs, and see the message

> The virtual machine has terminated unexpectedly during startup with
> exit code 1 (0x1). Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005)
> Component: MachineWrap Interface: IMachine
> {300763af-5d6b-46e6-aa96-273eac15538a}

when I try to start a VM in a terminal, I'm getting this error:

> VirtualBoxVM: Error -610 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
> VirtualBoxVM: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so",) failed:

> VirtualBoxVM: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.

I tried `sudo chown root:root /usr/lib`, but it didn't solve the problem.

I reinstalled my virtualbox and installed the latest version but when I want to run it I receive this error

> WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no
> module
> available for the current kernel (5.19.0-35-generic) or it failed to
> load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
>
> ```
>        sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
>
>      You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
> ```

- /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. There is not enough information here to offer any suggestions. Could you [edit] your question to include the steps you followed to install Ubuntu, and which specific errors you are receiving? With this, it may be possible to offer a solution 

Comment: Is virtualization enabled in the UEFI/BIOS?

Comment: Have you tired the "Tip" and reinstalled VirtualBox?

Comment: I checked, it's enabled in the BIOS. @JoepieEs

Comment: I edited the question. does it seem clear now?thank you for your reply @matigo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtualbox , Ubuntu 11.10 , linux-kernel 3: cannot start virtual machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71441/virtualbox-ubuntu-11-10-linux-kernel-3-cannot-start-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to excessive permission, and solved by

`sudo chmod go-w /usr /usr/lib /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so`

Answer (score 0):

### I asked a similar question a while ago and here is the answer that got me on track. My first guess, however, is that you should completely deinstall everything related to virtualbox and reinstall from the official release because that is supported.

Official Virtualbox from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads does not auto-update. You can stay on an old official version for as long as you wish. There is a pop-up informing of new versions, but it is merely informational, does not force the update and can be turned off.

If your Virtualbox is auto-updating it could mean a couple things:

You are running official Virtualbox, but you're interpreting the Update Available pop-up as an Update Required, then manually starting the update, which it isn't and you don't have to.

You're running the fork of Virtualbox provided and maintained by your Linux distro, and either they have wired into the fork an auto-updater or their package manager orders the update. They maintain and support their fork, so you'd have to ask them how to stop the auto-updating.

Please note that official Virtualbox has prerequisites, see https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02. ... nux-prereq .

We would recommend using official Virtualbox, placing proper weight on the Update Available pop-up as informational only, or shut it off, and then always run the matching Extension Pack, downloaded separately from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads. The EP can be uninstalled & installed inside the main Virtualbox window if your Linux host has a GUI, see the File menu, Preferences, Extensions. If you're running a text-only host, uninstall & install the EP using the 'vboxmanage extpack' command: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08. ... ge-extpack

Comment: I unistalled and removed every thing related to virtualbox, and checked if every thing is cleaned up. then reinstalled it from the official website. the problem is still existing.

Comment: "We would recommend using official Virtualbox, " Who's "we'? Why do their recommendations carry weight?

Comment: "We" is the Virtualbox website. You can get support there if you wish. By the way, is your user in the vboxusers group?